# Remove "Creative Cloud Files" from Finder sidebar?

Tags: macos, finder, adobe

I've used Activity Monitor to close every process with the Creative Cloud icon.

I've deleted the Creative Cloud Files directory itself, and deleted it from the trash.

I've gone to the "Extensions" preference pane and turned off "Core Sync."

I've quit Finder and restarted it.

And yet the "Creative Cloud Files" icon still shows up in my Finder sidebar, even though the original can't be found.

How can I eliminate this zombie icon once and for all?

Comment: Have you tried dragging icon out of the sidebar like you would if you were trying to remove an app from the dock?

Comment: Dragging the icon from the sidebar seems to do the trick... (no need to open preferences). Thanks, @NoahL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently one of the actions I mentioned in the question actually *did* solve the issue, but it required an actual log out and log in before it took effect.  Relaunching Finder wasn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as follows.

1) Go to the preferences in the Creative Cloud app and turn off file sync.

[image: turn off sync]

2) Go to your home folder and delete the Creative Cloud folder.

3) Relaunch Finder by pressing CMD + ALT + ESC, select Finder and press Relaunch.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to REMOVE Creative Cloud completely from your mac there is a [uninstaller link](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/help/uninstall-creative-cloud-desktop-app/_jcr_content/main-pars/download_section/download-1/file.res/Creative%20Cloud%20Uninstaller.zip) run it on your mac and it will be gone. (This is from adobe website: helpx.adobe.com So it's ok)

For more info go to [Creative Page link](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/help/uninstall-creative-cloud-desktop-app.html)

Comment: How does this affect Adobe software installed on my computer?

Comment: They say it's removing the Creative cloud app from your mac..

Comment: in certain scenarios like a corrupted Creative Cloud desktop app, or problems installing some Creative Cloud apps, you can uninstall the Creative Cloud desktop app.

For example, you may receive the following error message while updating the Creative Cloud desktop app:
They say it's removing the Creative cloud app from your mac.. 
Creative Cloud desktop failed to update. (Error Code: 2)

In such a situation, follow the steps below to uninstall, and then reinstall the Creative Cloud desktop app.

Answer (score -2):

**This is how you show / hide certain icons of the Finder Sidebar:**

Try a right-click on the folder, then *'Remove from Sidebar'*.

1) Go to *'Finder'*, then open *'Preferences'* from the menu bar
[image: Finder Menu bar]

2) Navigate to the *'Sidebar'* tab
[image: Sidebar (Finder)]

3) Uncheck the appropriate icon(s) as required. Then close.
I believe that apps like [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) can clean up these "ghost" directories too. However, based on your question, these steps should do the job. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Nope, it isn't listed in the finder preferences (which is probably the first hint this is a dirty hack going on). However, a suggestion by @NoahL to drag it from the sidebar (comment on the original question) seems to have worked (at least before restart...)